# Rails Tutorial 8.3 Authentication Test Not Passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rspec, tdd

I'm relatively new to RoR and going through Hart's Tutorial and ran into a little problem.  I hope you can help!

I finished chapter 8 and was trying to get the last test to pass, but I keep getting 1 failure. I'm new to all of this so any help would be appreciated.  I looked at other questions that were similar but haven't really found my solution.  And...I know it's just one test, but I'm super anal about these kind of things and I will not move on until I know 100% what I'm doing wrong.  Where is the disconnect? What am I not seeing here?

**Failure Test**

> No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
>   .........................................F......
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) Authentication signin followed by signout 
>        Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign out" }
>        Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>          Unable to find link "Sign out"
>        # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.67649 seconds 48 examples, 1 failure
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35 # Authentication
>   signin followed by signout
>
> Randomized with seed 40273

---

**Authentication_pages_spec.rb File**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
    end

    describe "followed by signout" do
      before { click_link "Sign out" }
      it { should have_link('Sign in') }
    end
  end
end
end
```

---

**sessions_controller.rb code**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' 
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper.rb code**

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?      
  end
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create new user with `FactoryGirl` only in one test `"with valid information"`. When you go to next test, you don't have this user, so you need to put this test in `do end` block `"with valid information"`.

```
describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin" do
    # You run it before all tests in this block
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      # So, here you visit signin_path and click "Sign in" link
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    # Before this test you only visit signin_path
    describe "with valid information" do
      # After this you create new user with FactoryGirl...
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      # ...and sign him in (before every test in this block)
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
    end

    # Here you again visit signin_path, but you don't have FactoryGirl user.
    # You can have this user, if you move this block to previous: "with valid information"
    describe "followed by signout" do
      before { click_link "Sign out" }
      it { should have_link('Sign in') }
    end
  end
end
```

So, refactor your code like this:

```
describe "with valid information" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

  it { should have_title(user.name) }
  it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
  it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
  it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign in') }
  end
end
```

This should help.

After finishing RailsTutorial, I advise you to read ["Everyday Rails: Testing with RSpec"](http://everydayrails.com). `should` pattern in testing is pretty outdated, and it is a good practice to use `expect -> to` pattern instead.

Comment: Awesomeness! That totally makes sense now and it worked! Thank you so much for your help and for the comments which really helped me understand the process of what's going on. I wish the Rails Guide had that.  I'll check out the book as well!